# AWS boto - upload file to S3 cause S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a bucket named: `db-backup-production` in region: `Ireland (s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)`

I'm trying to upload a file using the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the following error all the time

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

When i'm uploading using this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The upload works. What am i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get that to work with any of the suggestions?

Comment: Yes actually @Tom's answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are only doing a s3 "put", your policy should give you enough rights. However, if you are listing or getting the bucket object through an sdk, cli call etc, you also need rights on the bucket itself.

To provide these rights, use the "Resource" part of the policy as an array and add "arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production" as a resource in this array. I think about sth like this:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production/*", "arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production" ]
```

Comment: Do you have any technical reference/reason on why you need the dual resource reference like that?

Comment: nope, actually the first policy should work to put an object. I can't test right now, but i m pretty sure i faced a similar situation where I had to add the bucket resource as well. Worth to try it, but no link to documentation in this way though. Asaf, do you only perform a putObject from boto, or do you launch any other s3 action as well?

Answer (score 0):

When specifying S3 bucket permissions, you need to consider permissions for the bucket itself, and separately, permissions for the contents of the bucket.

One method is to require the specification of two resources for the same bucket:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production","arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production/*"]
```

The first resource specifies the bucket level scope and db-backup-production/* will be for object level scope.

However, you consider separate object and bucket level permissions in two statements as given in the below:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::db-backup-production/*"]
    }   ] }
```

This form give you more granular control over the resources, both bucket and object level.

See [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket)